# reference a class library in app code of an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net website with a reference to a class library. I can reference the class library in the aspx pages but how do I configure my site so that I can also reference the class library from a .cs file in app code?

Comment: what makes you think you can't access types in your class library from classes located in App_Code !? What are the error messages?

Comment: well, I have a class in app code and a reference to a class library in bin and I can't say something like using MyLibrary; in the class in app code

Comment: In my website project (not WAP) I see that I can reference the class library but there is no intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the reference in your project, you should be able to just add some `using` clauses to the top of your .cs files to import the code libraries

EDIT: you will need to add a using clause for the namespace of the library, not your project

Comment: This is correct, I think I must have been seeing a bug in Visual Studio as there was no intellisense until I reopened the project.